# Determining each unique process owner on linux system

Tags: linux, bash, awk, process

As the title says, im trying to make a bash script which gets each unique process owner on the system and calculates the total number of processes owned by that user as well as the sum of memory for all processes owned by that user. I know that `ps aux` displays all the info that i need, but how would i get each unique owner and store it in a variable so that i can get the needed info per user?

I was thinking to use `awk` to get the 1st column (username) and store the username in an `array`. I would use an `if` statement to check if the username is already in the array and if not, then add it. Except that i dont know how to use arrays in bash shell and this method doesnt seem like an effective way of doing it. Does anyone know of a more effective way of doing this?

Sample output

```
owner
Num Procs: 2, Mem: 3100, Curr CPU: 0
Hog: 00:00:00 sshd: owner@pts/16

root
Num Procs: 71, Mem: 52644, Curr CPU: 0
Hog: 01:33:41 /usr/bin/X :0 -br -audit 0 -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth -nolisten tcp vt7
```

Comment: Show the sample input that would produce that sample output so we can help you write a script to process that sample input.

Comment: i dont have a sample input, i have to create the input which is the script.

Comment: No. The desired script is a tool which transforms the input to the output. The input to the script is whatever the output of `ps aux` or whatever other command you are running produces. You have shown desired output from the script, now just post the input that the script would have received to produce that output from.

Comment: but thats the problem, i dont know what the input should be, all that i know is that ps aux displays everything i need, and use awk to get each column. But from there, im lost.

Comment: OK, so run `ps aux` and capture it's output. THAT is the sample input for the awk script. Now hand-edit a copy of that `ps aux` output to make it look like you want the awk script output to look. THAT is the sample output from the script. Post them both and we can help you. And if the `ps aux` output is 1,000 lines long then obviously trim it so some reasonable number of relevant lines, e.g. 10 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below `gawk` script should be helpful. Here i am redirecting the output of `ps -eo user,%cpu,%mem` to the `gawk` script.

The `gawk` script parses through the `ps` output and stores the users `cpu`, `mem` and `process` related information in an array and displays them.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

NR > 1 {
    array[$1]["cpu"]+=$2
    array[$1]["mem"]+=$3
    array[$1]["proc"]++
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
    for (users in array) {
        printf("User: %s\n",users)
        printf("Num Procs: %s, ", array[users]["proc"])
        printf("Mem: %s, ", array[users]["mem"])
        printf("Curr CPU: %s", array[users]["cpu"])
        print("\n")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ps -eo user,%cpu,%mem|./proc.awk
User: 102
Num Procs: 1, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: 105
Num Procs: 1, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: avahi
Num Procs: 2, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: colord
Num Procs: 2, Mem: 0.3, Curr CPU: 0

User: daemon
Num Procs: 1, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: dnsmasq
Num Procs: 1, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: root
Num Procs: 81, Mem: 0.8, Curr CPU: 1.2

User: rtkit
Num Procs: 1, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: statd
Num Procs: 1, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0

User: www-data
Num Procs: 5, Mem: 0, Curr CPU: 0
```

Note: This program uses features specific to `gawk` which should be available in your system by default.

Comment: the script doesnt work, im getting all kinds of error. Also, i notice that the script needs an args. Is is possible to create the script just by calling the proc.awk?

Comment: How are you running the script and what is the error msg you are getting ?

Comment: i am running the script on a linux shell command line by calling ps -eo user,%cpu,%mem|./proc.awk. I am getting syntax error at every 2d array used like array[$1]["cpu"] and the error points between the closing and opening square brackets.

Comment: 2D array is a `gnu awk` feature. Looks like your machine does not have `gnu awk` and might be having other alternatives like `mawk`. If you are using ubuntu/debian, then type `sudo apt-get install gawk` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing this entirely in bash, it's going to get quite awkward, and the end result will be hard to read. Although you can write quite complicated scripts in bash, bash is really meant to be used for writing scripts for automating straightforward, repetitive tasks. bash is really not well suited for doing complicated calculations, like that.

But, if you insist on using bash:

```
ls -ald /proc/[0-9]* | awk ' { print $3 } ' | sort | uniq -c
```

This gives you a count of how many processes on the system are currently running by each username.

```
for f in /proc/[0-9]*/stat; do echo `ls -l $f | awk ' { print $3 } '` `awk ' { print $24 * 4096 } ' <$f`; done | perl -e 'while(<STDIN>) { my @w=split; $n{$w[0]} += $w[1]; } print join("", map { "$_=$n{$_}\n"; } sort keys %n);'
```

This gives the total number of bytes of RAM used by each process. It reads the RSS column from /proc/stat, that gives the number of pages used by each process, and I believe that each pages is 4096 bytes on most common Linux platforms (adjust if needed, for your particular platform). Using VSZ, which is the virtual process size, is going to be misleading.

But as I just mentioned, bash isn't really the right tool, in my opinion, for this kind of hackery. Doing everything in Perl would probably be better, I'd think. In the end, I couldn't avoid resorting to some Perl hackery in the end, to add everything up. The equivalent bash code would be much longer, and complicated.

Comment: An ls of what directory?

Comment: What part of "which directory's ls output" you did not understand? And what array are you talking about? The two examples I gave you do not use arrays at all.